# PHP mysqli query to check if a row exist

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysql table, I want to check if a row exists where columnA=$a and $columnB=$b. I dont need to select anything from there. What should be efficient query for that? Currently Im doing like,

```
if ($stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE columnA=? && columnB= ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $a, $b);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $count=$stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    }
    return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE columnA=? && columnB=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $a, $b);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}

return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
```

Now you should be able to get it done

Answer (score 3):

That is efficient query if you want to improve that query you should select one column only to speed up the query.

```
if ($stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE columnA=? && columnB= ? LIMIT 1")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Select just one field from the row instead of all of them (`*`). Even though you're not using them, mysql still has to fetch them from storage and get them ready for transmission.

```
SELECT columnA FROM table WHERE ...
```

Otherwise there's not much else you can do to improve things, other than putting indexes on columnA and columnB to make the searching go faster.